# Magento paypal standard redirects only to blank page

Tags: paypal, redirect

After having installed a theme which does not interfere with the checkout except for some css formatting, the customer gets not redirected to paypal anymore but ends up at a blank page: **/paypal/standard/redirect/**

Nothing is written to the log files. The paypal module is enabled in config-advanced.

Magento version 1.9.0.1

I have no idea what the reason could be

Comment: There's probably an error message on that screen.  In your index.php, uncomment the `ini_set("display_errors",1);` line and try again.  Post the results here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, here is the error output: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')' in /chroot/home/***/***.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Standard.php on line 120`

Comment: @Sparc, did you find a solution to the problem? We are very curious what this could have caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have edited the app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Stan‌​dard.php file by mistake or that file didn't upload completely. Try replacing this file from a freshly downloaded archive of Magento. Make sure you download the same version that you're running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the file was corrupted for reasons unknown to me. I found that my file only had 120 lines of code while the original file has more than 200 lines.
I replaced it with the original and the redirect works as it should.
I have no idea how this could have happened as I went nowhere near this file and
the theme files didn't replace this file either.
Thanks for hinting at the error code function.